# ROS1: Save ROS Computation/Topic Graph

Tags: ros-noetic, rqt-graph, rosgraph

Using rqt_graph we can visualize the graph as well as save it in multiple formats. Is there a way to do it via a ros API or terminal command to save the graph in .png format.
rxgraph which is now deprecated used to support it but rqt_graph does not have any terminal arguments that stores the graph.

any help will be immensely appreciated.

Regards
Shouvik